# DroidAR Marker demos not working

Tags: java, android

I followed the steps in this website:
https://code.google.com/p/droidar/wiki/Markerdetection

But i m getting following errors when i tried to run it.:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1433): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  
 E/AndroidRuntime(1433):    at markerDetection.MarkerDetectionSetup.<init>(MarkerDetectionSetup.java:53)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(1433):    at de.rwth.MultiMarkerSetup.<init>(MultiMarkerSetup.java:28)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(1433):    at de.rwth.Main.onCreate(Main.java:16)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(1433):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(1433):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(1433):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(1433):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://parithi.com/2014/03/droidar-tutorial-getting-started-with-droidar/#prettyPhoto) may help you to get started

DroidAR has samples for Eclipse but no samples can be found for Android studio. If you want to use it in Android studio, add DroidAR library as a module in your project and make sure you added in gradle

`dependencies {
compile project(':droidAR')
}`

Launching the *TechDemoLauncher* will give you all the options available in DroidAR

Answer (score 0):

You have install opencv library for droidar.

You can just download opencv manager from google play store and install suggest package for your develop device.